# MCMC code comes into an error when increasing iterations

Tags: r, mcmc, odin

I am using MCMCpack to fit an age structured SIR model to seroprevalence data. I have the following code which includes an SIR model coded in Odin.

```
source("C:/Users/lra36/OneDrive - University of Cambridge/Documents/Varicella/Code/Odin/Model Run.R")
pop <- read.csv("C:/Users/lra36/OneDrive - University of      Cambridge/Documents/Varicella/Code/population/Model_population.csv")$x
population <- pop[3:23]
observations <- read.csv("C:/Users/lra36/OneDrive - University of Cambridge/Documents/Varicella/Code/input   CSVs/fitting data/UKHSA Seroprevalance.csv")$seropos
observations <- as.numeric(observations)/100
sigma <- read.csv("C:/Users/lra36/OneDrive - University of Cambridge/Documents/Varicella/Code/input CSVs/fitting data/UKHSA Seroprevalance.csv")$sd
sigma <- as.numeric(sigma)

B10 <- 0.95
B20 <- 0.99
B30 <- 0.15

params <- c(B10,B20,B30)

ModelSero <- function(params){
  B1 <- exp(params[1])
  B2 <- exp(params[2])
  B3 <- exp(params[3])

  Varicella_Final <- Varicella_Model$new(N_age=46,
                                     contact_matrix = as.matrix(Contact_Rate),
                                     n_births = births,
                                     ageing = ageing,
                                     beta = c(rep(B1,8), rep(B2,6), rep(B3,8), beta[23:46]),
                                     rho = rho,
                                     mort = mort,
                                     Sv_ini =Sv0,
                                     Ev_ini =Ev0,
                                     Iv_ini =Iv0,
                                     Sz_ini =Sz0,
                                     Iz_ini =Iz0,
                                     Rz_ini =Rz0,
                                     B_ini  =B0)

  # Runs the model for 100 years and creates a vector of seroprevalence that has the same structure as the UKHSA data

  model_results <- as.data.frame(Varicella_Final$run(100*365)[,])

  age <- c(1,1.5,2:20)
  model_results <- model_results[36501,] 
  S   <- as.numeric(model_results[6:26])
  E   <- as.numeric(model_results[52:72])
  I   <- as.numeric(model_results[98:118])


  seropos <- population - S - E - I 

  seroprev <- vector()
  for (i in 1:21) {
    seroprev[i]<- (seropos[i]/population[i])
  }
  return(seroprev)
}


prior_prob <- function(params){
  #creates a beta vector with random values for the values I am trying to fit, keeps the others fixed.
    B1 <- params[1]
    B2 <- params[2]
    B3 <- params[3]
dnorm(B1, mean=0, sd=1, log = TRUE) + dnorm(B2, mean=0, sd=1, log = TRUE) + dnorm(B3, mean=0, sd=1, log = TRUE)
}


logliklihood <- function(params, data){

  predictions <- ModelSero(params)
  log_likelihood <- vector()
  print(params)
  for (i in 1:21){
  log_likelihood[i] = observations[i] * log(predictions[i]) + (1 - observations[i]) * log(1 - predictions[i])
  }
  return(sum(log_likelihood))
}

tic <- Sys.time()                 #store start time of simulation
print(Sys.time())

Post_Sample <- MCMCmetrop1R(fun = function(params){logliklihood(params,observations) + prior_prob(params)},     theta.init = log(c(B10,B20,B30)), mcmc = 27, burnin=0)
(Sys.time()-tic)     #show duration of simulation run
beep(3)
```

I initially ran the model for 10 iterations and then tried to run it for 50 to get an idea of how long it was going to take. At this point I got the following error.

```
Error in MCMCmetrop1R(fun = function(params) { : `fun' returned NaN or NA
```

I understand that the chain is proposing parameter values that are resulting in NaN or NA values. I have done some investigating and found that after a certain amount of time the SIR function stops working and outputs INF and NA values. But now I don't know how to fix it?

I think I might have problems with my exp and logs but I can't see an error. Any ideas would be most welcome.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Unfortunately, your question is not reproducible because we (quite rightly!) don't have access to your C drive.  Please provide your input data by posting the output from `dput(pop[3:23])`, `dput(observations)` and `dput(sigma)` in your question.  If the results of those statements are unreasonably large, `dput(head(xxx))` may be workable alternative.

Comment: Since you are already printing `params`  in your log-likelihood function, that should give you some idea where the chain is headed when it gets in trouble, which should further give you some ideas about what to do about it. (Can't really say more than that without more information ...)